# How to define preprocessor definition for each configuration in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion, build-definition

I have several build profiles in `CLion -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake`. How can I set the preprocessor definitions for each profile, regardless of which compiler I use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake`.
2. Select the profile for which you want to set preprocessor definition.
3. Write in the `CMake options` field: `-DYOUR_DEFINE_VARIABLE=1`
4. In your CMakeLists.txt write the following:

```
if (YOUR_DEFINE_VARIABLE)
    add_definitions(-DYOUR_DEFINE_VARIABLE=1)
endif (YOUR_DEFINE_VARIABLE)
```

Comment: Newbie here, why does it neet to be set both in clion buid config and cmakelists ?

Comment: @Xmanoux As I understand, `-D` in CMake options just adds a local variable to cmake script, whereas `add_definitions` adds definitions (`-D`) to the compiler command line. More information: [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html), [cmake options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/manual/cmake.1.html#options)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this but this should work

```
if (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
        string(TOLOWER "${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}" CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES_LOWER)
else()
        string(TOLOWER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES_LOWER)
endif()

foreach(config ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES_LOWER})
        if (${config} MATCHES "debug")
                #add preprocessor definition something like this bellow
                add_definitions(-DFOO -DBAR ...)
        elseif(${config} MATCHES "release")
                #and so on...
        endif()
endforeach()
```

So, to correctly check strings, we convert build configuration types to lower case, and then we check if config from the type matches this custom configuration types. if it does, then we can add some preprocessor definitions, etc (

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} outputs nothing. I just realized that the `CMake` tab contains not cmake configurations, but build profiles.

Comment: Global `add_definitions` is a bad style in modern CMake. It's adviseable to use `target_compile_definitions` etc instead.

Comment: Didn't know. Thank you!